# MySQL Obtain the last value for a column not the first

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

This should be simple :)

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT rid, sid, sdata, max(id), min(FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch)) as fe, max(FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch)) as le, count(id) AS cnt
    FROM HID130
GROUP BY rid, sid
ORDER BY rid, sid DESC;

**OUTPUT:**
RID SID SDATA   MAX(ID) FE          LE          CNT
2   0   0   91152   2014-01-09 08:48:00 2014-01-09 08:48:00 1
2   2   4.52    100856  2013-12-18 02:40:00 2014-01-09 18:30:00 2814
2   1   13.5    100664  2013-12-18 02:39:00 2014-01-09 18:30:00 2514
```

Everything looks fine, with one exception sdata.

I would like to retrieve the last sdata value for a given RID/SID combination.  Currently I am getting the first sdata value for the RID/SID combination.

Any ideas what the best method would be to obtain the last sdata entry for the rid/sid combo?

Comment: This is the `greatest-n-per-group` problem, which has been answered many times on StackOverflow. Follow the tag link to see other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of query, I think the easiest way is to use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT rid, sid,
       substring_index(group_concat(sdata order by id desc), ',', 1),
       max(id), min(FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch)) as fe, max(FROM_UNIXTIME(epoch)) as le,
       count(id) AS cnt
FROM HID130
GROUP BY rid, sid
ORDER BY rid, sid DESC;
```

Comment: Think I need to brush up on substring_index ;)